# switch view control in IOS

Tags: view, ios4

Is there a equivalent to the below control in IOS, basically I am looking to display a list of items either as a list view (table) or as a coverflow view.?

[image: Switch view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Although you can consider what Apple has done for its music app. In portrait, it's a list view (`UITableView`) and in landscape, it's a cover flow view.